# Windows 8 installer folder grows exponentially

Tags: windows-8, window, windows-installer

I have Windows 8 x64 on my laptop. It is a while since its /windows/installer folder are growing! Right now it reaches to 160GB! I checked its content and it filled with .msp files with same size and same description but with different name! Would you please guide me through this problem?

Best regards.

Comment: Try running Disk Cleanup and selecting everything, especially Windows Update related files.

Comment: which description is shown? To which program does it belong to?

Comment: Different, for example I have 47 files with different file names but same title "Patch;access.accessde.accessolkaddin.accesswizard.ace.acewss.appdate.cdl mso.clview.csi.deployca.dw20.eurotool.excel.ex" with size of 759MB!

Comment: I already did disk cleanup for evey system and update files but nothing happens! Could it be some virus?

Comment: This looks like files from Microsoft Office. Remove office completely. Are the files gone?

Comment: No there are still there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a tool from some Chinese website to delete unused files. It seems that most of those files were unused! Here is the tool that I used:
http://appnee.com/wicleanup/